# navigation components - fitsSystemWindows not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making a app using SAA (Single Application Activity) and I want to have a gradient status bar, using the same gradient as my first view.

I'm doing some tests and I cant have a view over status bar, using `fitsSystemWindows` as false inside my parent layout.

Look what I have now:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
/>
```

This is my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="#c2c2c2"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

And I am setting this one inside my activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val window = window
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
```

Styles

```
   <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

PS:
When I FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS works fine, the only problem is when I have a form layout and I cant resize the screen. So, I'm aware of use FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS flag.